# Having a problem with SharedPreferences where it does not save a value to SharedPreferences. When called, only default value showing

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I'm having a problem with SharedPreferences. The same code works in one activity in another app, but does not work anywhere else within that app, and in this app it does not work at all. Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I have previously tried to create public final static String for the sharedprefand value keys, but even that didn't work. The code is.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SharedPrefs extends AppCompatActivity {

public int VO, VT, VTH;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    VO = 10;
    VT = 15;
    VTH = 25;

    SharedPreferences Stats = getSharedPreferences("STATS", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor StatEdit = Stats.edit();
    StatEdit.putInt("VOP", VO);
    StatEdit.putInt("VTP", VT);
    StatEdit.putInt("VTHP", VTH);
    StatEdit.apply();

}
```

And I'm receiving with

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MM extends AppCompatActivity {

Button b1, b2;
TextView text;
public int VO, VT, VTH;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_m_m);

    SharedPreferences Stats = getSharedPreferences("STATS", MODE_PRIVATE);
    VO = Stats.getInt("VOP", 0);
    VT = Stats.getInt("VTP", 0);
    VTH = Stats.getInt("VTHP", 0);



    b1 = findViewById(R.id.button);
    b2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    text = findViewById(R.id.textView);

    text.setText("YOU " + VO + VT + VTH);

}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Your code should work. By the way, have you opened `SharedPrefs` activity?

Comment: @snorlax No error message is shown. The code is not underlined in red either. I have used both StatEdit.apply(); and StatEdit.commit(); but neither worked. As I have stated, it works in one activity, but the same code, copied, and pasted in another activity does not work at all. In one activity, the values are saving as they should and laoding in another activity, but if I use // to deactivate the code and use the same code in another activity and change the values needed accordingly, it does not work at all.

Comment: @Unknown_2433 Yes, I opened the SharedPrefs activity in order to test the code.

Comment: Can you add
`System.out.println(""+Stats.getInt("VOP", 0)+"|"+Stats.getInt("VTP", 0)+"|"+Stats.getInt("VTHP", 0));`
after commit and check if the values are saving?

Comment: @Unknown_2433 the LogCat shows: I/System.out: 0

Could it be a problem with the structure of activity itself? Or do SharedPreferences load at the same time throughout the app? The variable I want to save is in an activity that comes after the main activity, and the activity I am trying to load the variable into is the main activity itself. 

I have gone from Main Activity > Second Activity > Main Activity again, but the SharedPreferences did not change at all.

Comment: But where is `SharedPrefs` and `MM` activity?

Comment: @Unknown_2433 I apologise for my stupidity, I was using this app to test the SharedPreferences. I found the answer. I needed to launch the activity before the SharedPreferences loaded in. I was calling SharedPreferences in activity MM which is my default activity from SharedPrefs activity without having loaded the SharedPrefs Activity, hence why the values were coming as null. I greatly appreciate the effort you and snorlax put in to answer my question. Thank you.

Comment: no problem. keep going

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no problem with the code. I thought SharedPreferences would automatically run and load all values when the app was started, but it turns out that the activities in which the SharedPreferences exist need to be opened in order for the method to be executed.

I would like to thank those that tried to help, I greatly appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences Stats = getSharedPreferences("STATS", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to (optional)

```
SharedPreferences Stats = getSharedPreferences("STATS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

---

```
 StatEdit.apply();
```

to

```
 StatEdit.commit();
```

you must provide change.